# Installer project visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

I am using visual studio community 2019. I am trying to add installer project template to my templates. I have installed the installer project extension yet I can't see the template. Is there anything missing?

Comment: Is this the one? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects

Comment: > Once you have finished installing the extension and restarted Visual Studio, you will be able to open existing Visual Studio Installer projects, or create new ones.

Comment: ...and once you're installed the extension, test if it's available by starting Visual Studio and selecting 'Create a New Project'. On the next screen in the search area make sure All languages/All platforms/All project types are selected in the dropdowns and then search for 'setup'.  If should find the Setup Project, Web Setup Project and Setup Wizard, which are some of the templates installed.

Comment: I found it. Thanks. I had not selected all languages/all platforms/all project types.